# tabs active link not working in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to open tab in modal with active link, but initially when modal is open no tab is active but it works when click on tabs.

Here is my html :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#modal1').leanModal({
    ready: function() {
      $('ul.tabs').tabs();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.leanmodal/1.1/jquery.leanmodal.min.js"></script>

<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div>
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a id="t1" class="active" href="#test1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="t2" href="#test2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a id="t3" href="#test3">Tab 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="test1">
      Tab 1 content
    </div>
    <div id="test2">
      Tab 2 content
    </div>
    <div id="test3">
      Tab 3 content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can active your first tab when initialization using `active` option. I modify your html to work. See snippet.

```
   $('ul.tabs').tabs({ active: 0 }); // O is index of tab
```

```js
$('#tab').tabs({
  active: 0
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div id='tab'>
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a id="t1" class="active" href="#test1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="t2" href="#test2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a id="t3" href="#test3">Tab 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="test1">
        Tab 1 content
      </div>
      <div id="test2">
        Tab 2 content
      </div>
      <div id="test3">
        Tab 3 content
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Code:

Using JqueryUi Script

Using JqueryUI StyleSheet

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#modal1").tabs();
});
</script>
<div id="modal1" class="modal" >
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div >
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li><a id="t1" class="active" href="#test1">Tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a id="t2" href="#test2">Tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a id="t3" href="#test3">Tab 3</a></li>
            </ul>
      
        <div id="test1">
            Tab 1 content
        </div>
        <div id="test2">
            Tab 2 content
        </div>
        <div id="test3">
            Tab 3 content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using import Script :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```